# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.irasethpharma.Cartmodelfirebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need help with this im stuck with it , i want to display my products on my cart by using firebase recycleview but it keeps on telling me cant convert object of type java.lang.string please help me solve this here is my code for my cart fragment activity

Comment: There's not enough information here for us to help. Please edit your question to show the [minimal code and JSON data (as text please, no screenshots) with which any of us can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Alternatively, have a look at the previous [questions about this error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+Can%27t+convert+object+of+type+java.lang.String+to+type).

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.